# Импорт функции из DLL

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, winforms

Мне необходимо импортировать функцию из DLL написанную на Delphi:

```
function MaterialLibraryCreate: real; stdcall;
```

Пытаюсь импортировать так:

```
[DllImport("dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public extern static void MaterialLibraryActivate(int a);
```

Но выходит эта ошибка:

> Вызов функции PInvoke "Xtreme3d-Test!Xtreme3d_Test.xtreme3d::MaterialLibraryActivate" разбалансировал стек. Вероятно, это вызвано тем, что управляемая сигнатура PInvoke не совпадает с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой. Убедитесь, что соглашение о вызовах и параметры сигнатуры PInvoke совпадают с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой.

А также при вызове функции:

```
function CameraSetViewDepth(camera,depth: real): real; stdcall;
```

Вот так:

```
[DllImport(path, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern double CameraSetViewDepth(double camera, double depth);
```

Выходит исключение:

> System.AccessViolationException: "Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена."

Comment: У вас же сигнатура явно не совпадает с указанной. Помимо этого, имена функций разные.

Comment: А на какой версии Delphi написана эта dll? Тип `real` является устаревшим и в современных компиляторах он является синонимом типу `double` (занимает в памяти 8 байт). Но когда-то давно, этот тип занимал в памяти 6 байт (сейчас этот тип называется `real48` и оставлен для обратной совместимости). И если ваша функция возвращает именно такой 6-ти байтовый тип, то вам очень "повезло" (см. [Convert Delphi Real48 to C# double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506942))

Comment: Эта DLL написана на Delphi 7 (на сколько я знаю).

Comment: В таком случае, это обычный `Double` (а не `int` как в вашем прототипе).

Comment: Такое объявление в Delphi означает функцию без параметров, возвращающую real. Так?

Comment: вероятно, так `public extern static double MaterialLibraryCreate()` (если экспортирована под таким именем)

Comment: С этим разобрался, но теперь новая ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если в функции на Delphi идёт возвращение real, то в C# это должна быть double.
2. Помогло то, что я поменял названия параметров на те, которые были в самой функции.

Comment: Напишите в ответе как же все-таки правильно импортировать, чтобы ответ был полезным для других участников.